# Delay function in qml

Tags: function, qml, delay, sine-wave

I have created a sine wave.
I added timer in the code and i try to call the delay but i am not able to get it.
I try to call near ctx.lineto but no use.
i need to add a delay between 1 plotting to another plotting.
Pls help me to solve this issue

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {

    function timer() {
        return Qt.createQmlObject("import QtQuick 2.0; Timer {}", root);
    }

    id: screen
    visible: true
    height: 1080
    width: 1920
    title: qsTr("SineWave")

    Rectangle {
        height: parent.height
        width: parent.width
        Timer {
            id: timer
        }

        function delay(delayTime, cb) {
            timer.interval = delayTime;
            timer.repeat = false;
            timer.triggered.connect(cb);
            timer.start();
        }
        Canvas {
            id: canvas
            anchors.fill: parent
            onPaint: {
                var ctx = getContext("2d");
                var cw = parent.width;
                var ch = parent.height;
                var  cx = cw, cy = ch/2;
                var w = width;
                var h = height;
                ctx.lineWidth = 4;
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(0, cy);

                for(var x=0;x<1921;x++){
                    var y = Math.sin(x/305);
                    ctx.lineTo(x, cy+(y*400));//now you add delay of 1sec
                    console.log(y)
                }//from here the sine wave is plotted from left to right clean the screen with small from left to right


                ctx.stroke();
                showMaximized(Window)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean with "delay between 1 plotting to another plotting"? Is the same data supposed to be displayed at a second plot at a later time? You will likely need a buffer for that, which I don't see here. Also the `Timer` object is sending out `timeout` signal, which you should handle, I don't see that here either

Comment: First i create a static sine wave now i was try to add delay from 1 point to another point
I try adding timer but i don't where to call the timer now check the code once

Comment: So you want each point to appear one second after the previous?

Comment: Yes @Amfasis can we solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses a `Timer` to increment a property called `step`. In the sine wave drawing `step` is used to limit the for loop to only draw lines until `step`.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window

Window {
    id: screen
    visible: true
    height: 1080
    width: 1920
    title: qsTr("SineWave")

    Rectangle {
        height: parent.height
        width: parent.width

        Timer {
            id: timer
            interval: 50
            running: true
            repeat: true
            onTriggered: {
                if (canvas.step > 1921)
                    timer.stop()
                canvas.step++
                canvas.requestPaint()
            }
        }

        Canvas {
            id: canvas

            property int step: 0

            anchors.fill: parent
            onPaint: {
                var ctx = getContext("2d")
                var cw = parent.width
                var ch = parent.height
                var cx = cw
                var cy = ch/2
                var w = width
                var h = height
                ctx.lineWidth = 4
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch)
                ctx.beginPath()
                ctx.moveTo(0, cy)

                for (var x = 0; x < canvas.step; x++) {
                    ctx.lineTo(x, cy + (Math.sin(x / 305) * 400))
                }

                ctx.stroke()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @sai-vineeth because you have read iam_peter's answer above and have even used it in a follow-up question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73932234/qml-canvas-step-is-cleaning-the-total-screen - it would be proper etiquette to acknowledge iam_peter's effort here and vote his answer up. Any concerns you had with iam_peter's answer, you should have raised it as a comment here and provided feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If you rewrite your `canvas.onPaint` to just paint one step of the sine wave, then, you can invoke `canvas.requestPaint()` repeatedly to paint different intervals of your sine wave with an appropriate delay. I implemented it but found the interval of 1000ms too slow, so, to make it a bit more interesting I reduce the interval to 10ms:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
Page {
    anchors.fill: parent
    title: qsTr("SineWave")
    Canvas {
        id: canvas
        anchors.fill: parent
        property int index: 0
        onIndexChanged: requestPaint()
        onWidthChanged: index = 0
        onHeightChanged: index = 0
        onPaint: {
            var ctx = getContext("2d");
            var cy = height/2;
            ctx.lineWidth= 4;
            if (index === 0) ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(index    , Math.sin( index      * Math.PI / 360) * cy + cy);
            ctx.lineTo(index + 1, Math.sin((index + 1) * Math.PI / 360) * cy + cy);
            ctx.stroke();
            if (canvas.index < parent.width) timer.start();
        }
        Timer {
            id: timer
            repeat: false
            interval: 10
            onTriggered: canvas.index++
        }
        BusyIndicator {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            running: canvas.index < parent.width
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://qmlonline.kde.org/?code=JYWwDg9gTgLgBARRggrsAxgazgJgHQCMArAFCiSyLJpZ4DCEAdjFBADYDOuhp508SVBkx4A6sEYATCAHduxEgAUAhgHMApnADeJOHrjLG6ABbQOeAGbA2bAFxwwyqOua79MYDDbr7ARw4AKlAAFABEAMoS6qLKAG7qoQCUbnp0hrHKXDr6OXDAkvbo6ZkpuYYmZpbWdg5OLjClOWCsYOqwAJ55zF2S6gAe9gAMjfpMAJJS-XTGhhoFcM6+KOocMCoSMMHJuaOM4pIwxtOz6vMSvX1wALxwwzt6TAAS6sCqxjDHjHP25-3XtyMHox1sx7Nl7jkMlA4OgYJcbhoPkwYP1NqEcJIkgBuQG5KEwzo3YwvN4wAD0OBxEJysL6eDYUX2hxuABYqdS9MALHBgr94VcboNEjC4Xh0N4nAAldSw4KDAA0t0VMnyh0VxNe70S7I5tLwACN1KoJCpDlsddS9SAIPEAhBeZNLvpFQBZZSHPAcCTBHp-XIAKjgbo9ijGcDJcAAzAA2IVwQPoToAagJ2txNNFDMY6jtDoucBTBFd7uMnu9eb+heFgeDpdD4ajserBILqYtEL1q1YmHU5vT+i5PKKjAy5j5cAAPLVnMw8CqDsZhR4QG1PTAnJs0xCAL64gKgNrafuc+bLtrHhbqVru+wWZScdQXjZtDI1Ah3DlwJhBV4aZzzYdRzwPkkyTXFdwhAAhFAOHaCZJAwd1oCPT8DCMUwoHMdB6jaCZ7EcGcGlQqAUEYRgJFUQpijHR1J2neo51VYxwNKXdtyAA)

Comment: hi Stephen Quan in your code u r using ctx.clearrect while it will clear rect full or from point to point

Comment: `if (index === 0) ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);` means when we are on the first step, we clear. For every other step, we do not clear, since, this is an incremental `onPaint` drawing the sinewave step-by-step. @saivineeth when will you start voting the answers that are helping you?